# How to get layer navigation category and Attributes in magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, layered-navigation

Magento 2.1 category page will be get some filters with attribute code and value.

After applying attribute code filters, how to get remaining **filterable attributes list** by programmatically. please help me anyone see the previous post [Get Remaining Filterable attributes after applying filters Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191589/get-remaining-filterable-attributes-after-applying-filters-magento-2).

am using this code see below

```
$filterableAttributes = $om->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList::class);

$layerResolver = $om->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver::class);
$filterList = $om->create(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList::class,
    [
        'filterableAttributes' => $filterableAttributes
    ]
);

$filterItemFactory = $om->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\ItemFactory');

$layer = $layerResolver->get();


 $layer->setCurrentCategory($categoryId);

 $filters = $filterList->getFilters($layer);
```

how to pass attribute code value as argument like category "`$layer->setCurrentCategory($categoryId);`".

Please help me through source code